# How to extract nouns using NLTK pos_tag()?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am fairly new to python. I am not able to figure out the bug. I want to extract nouns using NLTK.

I have written the following code:

```
import nltk

sentence = "At eight o'clock on Thursday film morning word line test best beautiful Ram Aaron design"

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)


length = len(tagged) - 1

a = list()

for i in (0,length):
    log = (tagged[i][1][0] == 'N')
    if log == True:
      a.append(tagged[i][0])
```

When I run this, 'a' only has one element

```
a
['detail']
```

I do not understand why?

When I do it without for loop, that is running

```
log = (tagged[i][1][0] == 'N')
    if log == True:
      a.append(tagged[i][0])
```

by change value of 'i' manually from 0 to 'length', i get the output perfectly, but with for loop it only returns the end element. Can someone tell me what is wrong happening with for loop.

'a' should be as follows after the code

```
['Thursday', 'film', 'morning', 'word', 'line', 'test', 'Ram' 'Aaron', 'design']
```

Comment: Hint: after your `for i` line, add `print(i)` inside the loop..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for i in (0,length):
```

This iterates over two elements, zero and `length`. If you want to iterate over every number between zero and `length`, use `range`.

```
for i in range(0, length):
```

Better yet, it's more idiomatic to directly iterate over the elements of a sequence, rather than its index. This will reduce the likelihood of typos like the one above.

```
for item in tagged:
    if item[1][0] == 'N':
      a.append(item[0])
```

Size-conscious users may even prefer the one line list comprehension:

```
a = [item[0] for item in tagged if item[1][0] == 'N']
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
>>> sentence = "At eight o'clock on Thursday film morning word line test best beautiful Ram Aaron design"
>>> nouns = [token for token, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)) if pos.startswith('N')]
>>> nouns
['Thursday', 'film', 'morning', 'word', 'line', 'test', 'Ram', 'Aaron', 'design']
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will only loop twice

```
for i in (0,length):
```

Once with `i = 0` and once with `i = length`

What you want is

```
for i in range(length):
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
import nltk

sentence = "At eight o'clock on Thursday film morning word line test best beautiful Ram Aaron design"

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)

tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)

length = len(tagged) - 1

a = list()

for i in range(0, length):
    log = (tagged [i][1][0] == 'N')
    if log == True:
        a.append(tagged [i][0])
print a
```