# Why my function is returning empty string in python?

Tags: python, nltk

What I am doing is, removing all parts of speech except nouns from a text.

I have written a function for that. It may not be the best or optimized code to do that because I have just started coding in python. I am sure the bug must be very basic but I am just not able to figure it out.

In my function two inputs go as parameters. One is the location of text on hard drive and other is the location of file where we want the output.

Following is the code.

```
def extract_nouns(i_location, o_location):
    import nltk

    with open(i_location, "r") as myfile:
      data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')        

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    length = len(tagged)
    a = list()

    for i in range(0,length):
       print(i)
       log = (tagged[i][1][0] == 'N')
       if log == False:
           a.append(tagged[i][0])

    fin = open(i_location, 'r')
    fout = open(o_location, "w+")

    for line in fin:
        for word in a:
           line = line.replace(word, "")
        fout.write(line)

    with open(o_location, "r") as myfile_new:
      data_out = myfile_new.read().replace('\n', '') 

    return data_out
```

When I call this function it is working just fine. I am getting the output on hard disk as I had intended but it does not return the output on the interface or should I say, it is returning a blank string instead of the actual output string.

This is how I am calling it.

```
 t = extract_nouns("input.txt","output.txt")
```

If you want to try it, take following as the content of input file

```
"At eight o'clock on 
Thursday film morning word line test 
best beautiful Ram Aaron design"
```

This is the output I am getting in the output file (output.txt) when I call the function **but the function returns blank string on the interface instead. It does not even print the output.**

```
"    
Thursday film morning word line test 
  Ram Aar design"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract nouns using NLTK pos\_tag()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409642/how-to-extract-nouns-using-nltk-pos-tag)

Comment: have you tried the previous code that i've suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409642/how-to-extract-nouns-using-nltk-pos-tag

Comment: @alvas it is a completely different problem. That is why i did not bring it over there. And i have tried your suggestion yet, i will once i figure this basic thing. I am very curious about what the bug is in my function. Could you please help me out.

Comment: I do not understand why people have downvoted this. Even though the questions have the same ground, but the problems are completely different. If i had changed the content nobody would have downvoted it. Just because the code is same does not mean the issues are also same.

Comment: i didn't downvote it but i think it's because your code should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. StackOverflow users are a little anal when it comes to "what is wrong with my code?" questions. =)

Comment: thank you alvas for whatever support you showed and suggesting codereview. I will keep that in mind from next time! Anyways problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file first:

```
for line in fin:
    for word in a:
       line = line.replace(word, "")
           fout.write(line)
fout.close()
```

Using `with` is usually the best way to open files as it automatically closes them and `file.seek()` to go back to the start of the file to read :

```
def extract_nouns(i_location, o_location):
    import nltk

    with open(i_location, "r") as myfile:
      data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(data)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    length = len(tagged)
    a = []

    for i in range(0,length):
       print(i)
       log = (tagged[i][1][0] == 'N')
       if not log:
           a.append(tagged[i][0])
    with open(i_location, 'r') as fin, open(o_location, "w+")  as fout:
        for line in fin:
            for word in a:
               line = line.replace(word, "")
            fout.write(line)
            fout.seek(0) # go back to start of file
            data_out = fout.read().replace('\n' , '')
        return data_out
```

Comment: Jesus! I would not have never figured it out! Thank you so much Padraic. I was going nuts over this bug. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, I added code using seek and with to open all the files. If you use `with` forgetting to close files will not be a problem again!

Answer (score 0):

The last statement in the function should be the `return`.

Because there is the `print data_out`, you return the return value of `print` which is none.

E.g:

```
In []: def test():
   ..:       print 'Hello!'
   ..: 

In []: res = test()
Hello!

In []: res is None
Out[]: True
```

Comment: which version of python are you using? What is the error traceback?